# better understand of heap stack and list

Tags: c++, heap-memory

have this code:

```
void set(list<Person*>* listP){
    Person timmy = Person(10);
    listP->push_back(&timmy);
}
int main()
{
    list<Person*> listP;
    set(&listP);
    Person* timmy  = listP.back();
}
```

If i understand correct (please correct me) timmy is allocated on the stack , so i cannot count on the values of timmy when i use them in the main. Am i correct? do i need to create timmy like this:

```
Person* timmy = new Person(10);
```

in order to create it on the heap and not on the stack ,so it will not be destroyed after method return?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void set(list<Person*>* listP){
    Person timmy = Person(10); // create timmy on automatic storage (stack)
    listP->push_back(&timmy); //push timmy's address
} //timmy is destroyed. pushed address points to deallocated memory
```

Yes, you need to use `Person* timmy = new Person(10);` to allocate on heap.

```
void set(list<Person*>* listP){
    Person *timmy = new Person(10); // timmy is a pointer now
    listP->push_back(timmy); //push timmy's copy (copy of pointer)
} //timmy (pointer) is destroyed, but not the memory it points to
```

Also prefere to use `smart_pointers` such as `std::shared_ptr`, `std::unique_ptr` or `boost` smart pointers. It will simplify memory management and writing `exception-safe` code

Comment: @user1495181: Your understanding is correct but the conclusion isn't necessarily, you could use `list<Person>` instead of `list<Person*>`. That would avoid these problems.

Comment: Thank you for correction. yes it will avoid but will copy new instance.

Comment: @user1495181: Sure, and the problem with that is ...?

Comment: @user1495181: don't make optimization until you found a bottleneck. Write clean well readable code and care about optimizations only when you must

Comment: Performance , at least in my case. i load 100K records from DB for each of them i create RecordIntance fill values and add it to list (with list<Record> for each record you will create 2 instances. one for read and additional when you add to the list). After i create this list i return the list to the caller if it list<Record> , so now again the complete list will be copied. i am new to cpp , so please correct me.

Comment: Andrew, i agree with you (premature optimization is root of evil), but in this case i know the the cost. look on my comment above.

Comment: Return value optimization will most likely kick in here. Not sure what the exact conditions for rvo are, but I never failed to meet them so far. Making copies of 100k elements twice is likely faster than performing 100k heap allocations, unless your elements are very heavy weight.

Comment: @user1495181: take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809120/creating-and-returning-a-big-object-from-a-function

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is correct, but you don't **have** to create `timmy` on the "heap", if you use a `list` of `Person`s instead:

```
void set(list<Person>& listP){
    listP.push_back(Person(10));
}
```

<strike>It is extremely likely that no extra person copies will be made in the `push_back` ([copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision))</strike>. In C++11, even if the copy wasn't elided, move semantics could kick in and expensive copying.

Comment: are you talking about RVO? isnt it used only for big object? see the discussion bellow. thank you!

Comment: @user1495181 RVO is a subset of copy elision, and it applies to returning by value. So it doesn't apply to this example. I was speculating that the push_back would only make one construction, but it actually makes that plus a copy construction. But with C++11, the temporary `Person` is move-copied.

Comment: @user1495181 I forgot to say, RVO has nothing to do with the size of the object being returned.

Comment: I test to see if listP.push_back(Person(10)); dosnt create two objects (in c++11) and it does.