# How should I properly return a vector from a function to avoid extra copying?

Tags: c++

How should I properly return a vector from a function to a void extra copying?

If I return just vector then I should create a vector in the function
and then on return it will be copied in the result. But I want to avoid that.
Then I guess I should create the vector on the heap and return a pointer to it
vector* ?

Thanks

Comment: You can look into references, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752658/is-the-practice-of-returning-a-c-reference-variable-evil

Comment: http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/

Comment: Just return it by value, unless you are completely sure that your compiler does not elide the copy and you don't have C++11 move semantics.

Comment: There is also 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809120/creating-and-returning-a-big-object-from-a-function and 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134831/in-c-is-it-still-bad-practice-to-return-a-vector-from-a-function The latter is of particular interest if you can use C++11.

Answer (score 2):

*The C++ Standard* allows your compiler to eliminate this copy in certain cirumstances (Section 12.8.5). It's difficult to tell whether your compiler actually does this, so you should read its documentation or look at generated assembler code. So it's probably better to let your compiler do optimisations for you.

But if you really like optimising by hands (you shouldn't), read on.

Allocating vector on heap and returning a pointer to it is a bad thing to do, because in this case it is not clear who's responsible for this object and who'll do memory cleanup.

Making your function take an additional argument—reference or pointer to a vector to store result into—is way better.

Comment: And returning a value is way, way better.

Comment: @juanchopanza OK, I'll mention it…

Comment: I'm still missing any mentioning of move semantics in an answer with already 2 upvotes.

Comment: Note that, at elast with not too ancient versions of GCC, clang and MSVC, return value optimization is the norm, so you can be pretty confident it will take place (of course, if it matters, you can always check to be sure).

Answer (score 1):

I would pass a reference to it as a parameter.

```
void foo(std::vector& bas)
{
// do code here
}
```